# Caliburn Micro - how to use multiple views over a single viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use several different views referring to the same viewmodel, depending on the context.

This is what I've got:

- ModuleViewModel.cs (containing "class ViewModels.ModuleViewModel")
- Model.Overview.xaml (containing "x:Class="Views.Module.Overview")

but the call (I need to do it manually from a utilities library of mine) to `ViewLocator.LocateForModel(*viewModel*, null, "Overview")` doesn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong? I read the CM documentatione and it seems allright...

Thanks in advance
!

Comment: Is that `Views.Module.Overview` a typo? If not that's the issue - the namespace must match the root VM name (it must be `Views.Model.Overview`)

Comment: Well, yes, it's a type defined in the xaml, as I wrote. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually have an `Overview` usercontrol in the `Views.Module` namespace, this won't be found by CM

CM will search by removing the `Model` part of the original VM namespace/type name. I can't remember the exact rules, but you can customise them

For the default rules the correct namespace should be `Views.Model.Overview`

You might want to check out the documentation for name transformation:

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%2fViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation

Also:

Since you have called your VM `ModelViewModel` I can only hazard a guess that the nametransformer may strip the `Model` from the start of your VM name too (though I **think** the regex only checks the end of the string so you might be ok!)

So assuming the above namespace change doesn't work you might end up with a target View name of... I don't know what!

Finally - it might be worth implementing a debug logger - CM writes a lot of info against a log interface, you just need to provide a `GetLog` method that provides an implementation of `ILog` (one that writes to the `Debug` stream is usually good enough for troubleshooting)

You can do this in `Bootstrapper.Configure` (or anywhere else that's early enough) by providing your own `Func` for `LogManager.GetLog`

```
LogManager.GetLog = (type) => { return new DebugLogger(); };
```

And implement `ILog` in `DebugLogger` (leave that one to you!)

EDIT: Try reimplementing the `LocateForModel` func in your bootstrapper code:

```
        ViewLocator.LocateForModel = (model, displayLocation, context) =>
        {
            var viewAware = model as IViewAware;
            if (viewAware != null)
            {
                var view = viewAware.GetView(context) as UIElement;
                if (view != null)
                {
                    LogManager.GetLog(typeof(ViewLocator)).Info("Using cached view for {0}.", model);
                    return view;
                }
            }

            return ViewLocator.LocateForModelType(model.GetType(), displayLocation, context);
        };
```

Then you can debug (this is what I've ripped from the source from v1.4 so you might want to look at the source again since 1.5 is out depending on what you are using)

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae616b841924#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/ViewLocator.cs

Edit: It's also the Silverlight version (I've just ripped out some of the compiler conditionals) so you do want to grab the latest version from source!

Comment: SORRYYYYYYY!!!!! I misspelled the word "Module"!!! My "model" entity is called "Module", so it's viewmodel is called "ModuleViewModel"!! Sorry, I edited the original message and now it's right. I understand what you said but with the "right version" of my message I think it's not that true anymore. Sorry again, can you help me again now?

Comment: Try implementing `ILog` as I've suggested, CM will write the namespaces it searched for into the log. I'm looking at the source - do you get  a 'Could not locate view for model' message in place of where the view should be?

Comment: Exactly, that's the message I'm getting.

Comment: So it's not finding the VM at all - so it must be that the VM resolution isn't locating the view. Can you post the code for your ViewModel and View. Also can you try implementing `ILog` and write to the debug stream to see what namespaces CM searched

Comment: Sure I'm going to implement ILog and give information. Thanks

Comment: I did it, but CM is not giving me any message about the failed view resolution.... (while logging a lot of other things). I put a breakpoint on the code line where I'm trying to let it resolve my view, it returns nothing and don't log anything.... :'(

Comment: The next thing is probably to copy the implementation of `ViewLocator.LocateForModel` and paste it into your bootstrapper. I've edited my answer - at least then you can debug it and find out exactly what it's doing. I suspect you are doing something wrong but you never know, CM isn't bug free yet (nothing ever is!)

Comment: Just on the off chance that you've missed this...you have implemented `IViewAware` on your model right? Otherwise it's `ViewLocator.LocateForModelType` that you want to look at instead

Comment: I solved it. I was desperate, when I noticed that ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType implementation was overridden (not by me, by someone else, but in the utility library I'm using) without calling back the original caliburn implementation, so the real naming convention that was applied was different from the default one..... tahnk you very much for your great help!

Comment: No probs - I bet there was no documentation :) always the way!